Does the apparent creativity of AI, like GPT, challenge Chomsky's claim that only humans possess a uniquely creative capacity for language?
Chomsky argued that the creative use of language is a uniquely human ability, one that machines inherently lack. In Cartesian Linguistics, he built on Descartes' notion that human language, due to its creativity and ability to form infinite combinations from finite means, could not be explained in mechanical terms. This creativity, Chomsky argued, supported his theory of an innate linguistic faculty.
However, the rise of AI models like GPT seems to blur the distinctions Chomsky and Descartes drew between human creativity and mechanical processes. Unlike machines of the industrial era which operated strictly within the bounds of cause and effect, today’s AI systems appear less constrained by circumstances or stimuli. These intelligent programs generate responses that feel novel, context-aware, and capable of “using finite elements in infinite ways,” as Humboldt described.
Given this, where does the debate stand now? Does the apparent creativity of AI challenge the idea that only humans possess the capacity for “true” linguistic creativity, or are these models still fundamentally different from the human mind?
Note: This is not a debate about the quality of AI-generated content or whether it can compete with human creativity. The focus is on a deeper distinction: before AI, machines operated on simple cause-and-effect principles, producing fixed outputs (e.g., a doll that always says "mom"). In contrast, AI systems can generate endless variations—like paraphrasing a sentence 1,000 different ways—showing a capacity for flexibility and novelty that challenges traditional notions of mechanical constraints.

What exactly Chomsky meant about language use being unique to humans has changed somewhat over time, as different experiments have been performed and different counterexamples have come to light.
However, "using finite elements in infinite ways" is something computers have been able to do for decades now, as Chomsky clearly knew. In his own terminology, a "type-three grammar" can do this (better known as a DFA or regular expression). So clearly that's not what he had in mind with this claim.
P.S. I'm not sure your distinction between "simple cause-and-effect principles" and "AI" holds up. Neural networks have existed since the 1950s, and obfuscating the chain of cause and effect in a black box doesn't make it disappear.

So, I infer from the explanation that while neural networks, earlier computational models, and modern AI software may generate outputs that resemble infinite variations, they fundamentally operate on input-driven processes—even if the chain of causation is obscured by complexity.

@user49607 Exactly!


Unlike machines of the industrial era which operated strictly within the bounds of cause and effect, today’s AI systems appear less constrained by circumstances or stimuli.

You can totally build a wheel of fortune which operates strictly according to classical deterministic examples but has a 'surprising', random result every time you turn it; likewise, one ingredient to current generative AI tools is a 'surprising' number that is delivered by a PRNG, a pseudo-random number generator, which is commonly implemented as a deterministic algorithm that starts with a (normally hidden) seed and progresses—if you know the seed—through a large number of states that will eventually, after many, many steps, circle around and start anew.
Likewise, the whack-a-mole game manages to surprise players: is it intelligent, creative, sentient?

These intelligent programs

Now you managed to bake your preferred answer into the question I'm afraid

The argument that systems like a wheel of fortune or PRNG produce surprising results without intelligence, and that generative AI’s novelty is similarly reducible to deterministic mechanisms, presupposes its conclusion: that AI systems are fundamentally equivalent to such deterministic systems. This risks overlooking distinctions raised in the question, such as AI’s context-aware flexibility and linguistic adaptability.
Framing the debate this way might bypass the original focus: whether AI’s capacity for infinite generation from finite means (Humboldt) challenges mechanical determinism.
